# Running the client via IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, corda

I am new to Corda and following [this](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#the-example-cordapp) link. I am running from IntelliJ by selecting "Run Example RPC Client" from run configuration and click on green arrow. And I am getting the error on logs as below :

```html
Exception in thread "main" ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787)
at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:191)
at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:123)
at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:86)
at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:204)
at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:196)
at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:109)
at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:135)
at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:120)
at com.example.client.ExampleClientRPC.main(ExampleClientRPC.kt:31)
at com.example.client.ExampleClientRPCKt.main(ExampleClientRPC.kt:16)
```

Below is the screenshot after I have started "**Run Example CorDapp - Kotlin**".[image]

Also below is the screenshot of of client : **[image: Edit Configuration]**

Comment: I've updated the Example CorDapp to hardcode the ports used by the node driver and update the port used by the RPC client. Try pulling the latest changes and seeing if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,Port number that is coming in the configuration is 10006 it should be 10008 and **I hope your nodes running correctly**.

You can edit the run configuration for the com.example.client.ExampleClientRPC in the Intllij

Run -> edit configuration
edit "program Arguments" to 10008.It should work.[image]

- Second option : you can run the task ***./gradlew runExampleClientRPCJava*** after running the ***deployNodes task***
  from the terminal/command prompt.

Comment: it is still giving the same exception as in my question. I have also tried it from command line and again it is giving same errors.

Comment: i tried with same same code in github it has issue with intellij configuration as i mentioned above .Please make sure deployTask has run and corda nodes are running with same port you want to connect. It worked for me or you can share your code

Comment: I have added 2 screenshots  in my question of console log after running  "Run Example CorDapp - Kotlin" and edit configuration screen for Kotlin client.